# Getting error when running Nightmare.js on PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, nightmare

PhpStorm error trying to run Nightmare.js app

```
Error: write EPROTO 140157120179072:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252:
```

Comment: running node on ubuntu. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the result of running same app in terminal?

Comment: also, are you using proxy? Please provide a full output you can see in console when running your app